# Slice MySQL Result

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a database named "library" with the following tables:

```
+-------------------+
| Tables_in_library |
+-------------------+
| books             |
| shelves           |
+-------------------+
```

Books are stored in the shelves, and I want to return only four (4) books per shelf in a query. If the shelf have more than 4 books, that shelf must be displayed twice without repeating the already displayed books.

This is the shelves table:

```
+----+------+---------------------------------+
| id | uid  | description                     |
+----+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | 1000 | Book and TV Storage Combination |
|  2 | 1001 | Shelving Unit                   |
+----+------+---------------------------------+
```

and the books table:

```
+----+------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | uid  | shelf | title                                              |
+----+------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | 1000 | 1000  | The Mythical Man-Month                             |
|  2 | 1001 | 1001  | Code Complete                                      |
|  3 | 1002 | 1000  | The Art of Computer Programming                    |
|  4 | 1003 | 1001  | The Pragmatic Programmer                           |
|  5 | 1004 | 1001  | Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs  |
|  6 | 1005 | 1000  | Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools       |
|  7 | 1006 | 1001  | The C Programming Language                         |
|  8 | 1007 | 1001  | Introduction to Algorithms                         |
|  9 | 1008 | 1000  | Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture    |
| 10 | 1009 | 1001  | Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code |
| 11 | 1010 | 1001  | Design Patterns                                    |
+----+------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

I am going to print the result using JSON and this is how I do it:

```
function getShelves(){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shelves") or die(mysql_error());
    return $query;
}

function getBooksFromShelf($shelf){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books WHERE shelf = '$shelf'") or die(mysql_error());
    return $query;
}

$response = array();
$shelves = getShelves();
while($s = mysql_fetch_assoc($shelves)){
    $books = getBooksFromShelf($s["uid"]);
    $bookList = array();
    while($b = mysql_fetch_assoc($books)){
        $bookList[] = array(
            "uid" => $b["uid"],
            "title" => $b["title"]
        );
    }
    $response[] = array(
        "shelf" => $s["uid"],
        "books" => $bookList
    );
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

And this results into:

```
[
{
    "shelf": "1000",
    "books": [
        {
            "uid": "1000",
            "title": "The Mythical Man-Month"
        },
        {
            "uid": "1002",
            "title": "The Art of Computer Programming "
        },
        {
            "uid": "1005",
            "title": "Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools"
        },
        {
            "uid": "1008",
            "title": "Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture "
        }
    ]
},
{
    "shelf": "1001",
    "books": [
        {
            "uid": "1001",
            "title": "Code Complete "
        },
        {
            "uid": "1003",
            "title": "The Pragmatic Programmer"
        },
        {
            "uid": "1004",
            "title": "Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs"
        },
        {
            "uid": "1006",
            "title": "The C Programming Language"
        },
        {
            "uid": "1007",
            "title": "Introduction to Algorithms"
        },
        {
            "uid": "1009",
            "title": "Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code"
        },
        {
            "uid": "1010",
            "title": "Design Patterns"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

The second shelf contains 7 books so therefore it must be displayed twice, the first 4 and the last 3 books. This is were I get stuck. Thank you for your responses!

Comment: Can you explain why you need to split those up?  Also, why are you not returning all shelves and books in the same query -- hitting the database within loops can be expensive.

Comment: I am going to display it into slides with each slide containing 4 books. I am using a jquery plugin called rhinoslider to present the books

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array_chunk to split larger arrays in pieces e.g. in your case of 4:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

```
$pieces = array_chunk($bookList, 4);
foreach($pieces as $bookRow) {
    $response[] = array(
        "shelf" => $s["uid"],
        "books" => $bookRow
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's pretty straight forward answer. Cheers!